Does every extreme functional attain its norm?
Define $S_X=\{x\in X:\|x\|=1\}$ and $B_X=\{x\in X:\|x\|\leq 1\}$. A functional $f\in S_{X^*}$ is called $\bf{extreme}$ if it cannot be written as a convex combination of more than or equal to two points in $B_{X^*}$.
I want to prove or disprove that for a Banach space $X$, an extreme functional $f\in X^*$ attains its norm. $X^*$ is the dual space of $X$.
We know that $X$ is reflexive if and only if all $f\in X^*$ attain its norm. But in general all functionals do not attain its norm.
Is there any example of a Banach space where all extreme functionals do not attain its norm?
I am not able to get an example. Please help me. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

The only lead that I have would be that $B_{X’}$ is compact for the weak-$*$ topology, but I’m not sure of how it would be relevant

Even though this information is known to me but I could not able to build a counterexample.

I think you can probably find a counterexample with $C([0,1])$ with uniform norm. Using Riesz theorem or something like that.

One thing which I know about $C([0, 1])^$ is that the extreme points of $C([0, 1])^$ with respect to probability measure are the point measure with unit mass. But this point measures attain their norm. Can you please help me further?

I do not have much idea about $C[0, 1]^*$. If possible could you please elaborate the answer? Please

It was also a false lead form me sorry. I went into the details and it does not really work as I intended

It's ok. Totally helpless I am.

This is false. Let $X$ be a non-reflexive Banach space such that $X^*$ is strictly convex. Then every $f \in B_{X^*}$ is an extreme point due to strict convexity but by Jame's theorem there is $f \in B_{X^*}$ that is not norm attaining.
I can't think of an easy example of a Banach space $X$ such that $X^*$ is strictly convex and not reflexive, but such spaces exist. For example, any separable dual space $X^*$ admits a strictly convex renorming.

Thank you very much for your answer.

Do have any idea about: If $X$ is non-reflexive such that $X^$ is not strictly convex then there always exists $f\in \operatorname{ext}(B_{X^})$ such that $f$ is not norm attaining?

I do not at the moment
